# Проблема с обработкой платежа python 3.10 (aiogram и pyqiwip2p)

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram, pyqiwi

Писал код для бота в telegram(aiogram or pyQiwiP2P), создание ссылки и оплата проходят без проблем, но проверка платежа нет, нажимая на кнопку обработки начинается загрузка, после чего бот замолкает, не знаю что делать...

**main.py**

```
import logging
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import State, StatesGroup
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage

import markups as nav
import config as cfg
from db import Database
from pyqiwip2p import QiwiP2P
import random


logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

bot = Bot(token=cfg.TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=MemoryStorage())

db = Database("database.db")
p2p = QiwiP2P(auth_key=cfg.QIWI_TOKEN)

class Payment(StatesGroup):
    wait_sum = State()

def is_number(_str):
    try:
        int(_str)
        return True
    except  ValueError:
        return False

@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def command_start(message: types.Message):
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        if not db.user_exists(message.from_user.id):
            db.add_user(message.from_user.id)

        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Здравствуй дорогой {0.first_name}!"
                                                     "\n"
                                                     "\nЗдесь вы можете :"
                                                     "\nКупить читы, узнать о новостях и лайфхаках в играх!"
                                                     "\n"
                                                     "\nМы не храним вашу информацию, все полностью конфиденциально!".format(message.from_user), reply_markup=nav.mainMenu)

@dp.message_handler()
async def command_start(message: types.Message):
    if message.text == 'ST':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, '️Купить читы')

    elif message.text == '️Купить читы':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Выберите игру!', reply_markup = nav.ChFoGaMeMenu)

    elif message.text == 'Hot Новости':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Выберите дату!', reply_markup = nav.newsMenu)

    elif message.text == '️Лайфхаки дня':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Выберите жанр игры!', reply_markup=nav.LiHaMenu)

    elif message.text == 'О боте':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Хоешь узнать обо мне?!', reply_markup=nav.aboutthebotMenu)

    elif message.text == 'Профиль':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Ваш аккаунт'.format(message.from_user), reply_markup=nav.myaccMenu)

    elif message.text == 'Главное меню':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Вы в главном меню', reply_markup=nav.mainMenu)

    #Читы для игр
    elif message.text == 'CS-GO':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, '\nОплатить товар [CS-GO] 75₽', reply_markup=nav.topUpMenu)

    elif message.text == 'Dota2':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, '\nОплатить товар [Dota2] 75₽', reply_markup=nav.topUpMenu)

    elif message.text == 'Call Of Duty:Black Ops':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, '\nОплатить товар [Call Of Duty:Black Ops] 75₽', reply_markup=nav.topUpMenu)

    elif message.text == 'PUBG':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, '\nОплатить товар [PUBG] 75₽', reply_markup=nav.topUpMenu)

    elif message.text == 'Standoff2':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, '\nОплатить товар [Standoff2] 75₽', reply_markup=nav.topUpMenu)

    elif message.text == 'Главное меню':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Вы в главном меню', reply_markup=nav.ChFoGaMeMenu)

    #Новости для игр
    elif message.text == 'Today news':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Today↓↓↓', reply_markup=nav.ntodayMenu)

    elif message.text == 'Yesterday news':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Yesterday↓↓↓', reply_markup=nav.nYetodayMenu)

    elif message.text == 'Главное меню':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Вы в главном меню', reply_markup=nav.ChFoGaMeMenu)

    #Лайфхак для игр
    elif message.text == 'Шутеры':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Лайфхаки для [Шутеров] читай в Teletype↓↓↓', reply_markup=nav.ShootMenu)

    elif message.text == 'ММОРПГ':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Лайфхаки для [ММОРПГ] читай в Teletype↓↓↓', reply_markup=nav.MMORPGMenu)

    elif message.text == 'Стратегии':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Лайфхаки для [Стратегии] читай в Teletype↓↓↓', reply_markup=nav.Strateg2Menu)

    elif message.text == 'MMO Action[скоро!]':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Лайфхаки для [MMO Action] читай в Teletype↓↓↓', reply_markup=nav.MMOA2Menu)

    elif message.text == 'Главное меню':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Вы в главном меню', reply_markup=nav.ChFoGaMeMenu)


    #О боте для игр
    elif message.text == 'Кто я?':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Основная информация о боте указана в teletype!', reply_markup=nav.Whoiam2Menu)

    elif message.text == 'Соглашение':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Основная информация о пользовательском соглашении указана в teletype!', reply_markup=nav.Sogl2Menu)

    elif message.text == 'Главное меню':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Вы в главном меню', reply_markup=nav.ChFoGaMeMenu)

    #Профиль игрока
    elif message.text == 'Главное':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, '\nВаш аккаунт: {0.first_name}'
                                                     '\n'
                                                     '\nКоличество покупок: '.format(message.from_user), reply_markup=nav.myaccMenu)

    elif message.text == 'Мои покупки':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, '\nВаши покупки: '.format(message.from_user), reply_markup=nav.myaccMenu)


    elif message.text == 'Главное меню':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Вы в главном меню', reply_markup=nav.ChFoGaMeMenu)

@dp.message_handler(state=Payment.wait_sum)
async def bot_mess(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    if message.chat.type == "private":
        if is_number(message.text):
            message_money = int(message.text)
            if message_money == 5:
                comment = str(message.from_user.id) + "_" + str(random.randint(1000, 9999))
                bill = p2p.bill(amount=message_money, lifetime=15, comment=comment)

                db.add_check(message.from_user.id, message_money, bill.bill_id)

                await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f"Оплатить счет {message_money}₽ за данный товар по кнопке\n \nКомментарий к оплате {comment}", reply_markup=nav.buy_menu(url=bill.pay_url, bill=bill.bill_id))

            else:
                await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Минимальная сумма для доната 75₽!')
        else:
            await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Введите целое число!')

            await state.finish()



@dp.callback_query_handler(text="top_up")
async def top_up(callback: types.CallbackQuery):
    await bot.delete_message(callback.from_user.id, callback.message.message_id)
    await bot.send_message(callback.from_user.id, "Чтобы перейти к оплате, введите число 75!")
    await Payment.wait_sum.set()

@dp.callback_query_handler(text="check_")
async def top_up(callback: types.CallbackQuery):
    bill = str(callback.data[6:])
    info = db.get_check(bill)
    if info != False:
        if str(p2p.check(bill_id=bill).status) == "PAID":
            user_money = db.user_money(callback.from_user.id)
            money = int(info[4])
            db.set_money(callback.from_user.id, user_money+money)
            await bot.send_message(callback.from_user.id, "Ваш счет оплачен!")

        else:
            await bot.send_message(callback.from_user.id, "Вы не оплатили счет!", reply_markup=nav.buy_menu(False, bill=bill))
    else:
        await bot.send_message(callback.from_user.id, "Счет не найден!")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates = True)
```

**markups.py**

```
from aiogram.types import ReplyKeyboardMarkup, KeyboardButton
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton

btnMain = KeyboardButton('Главное меню')

# ---Main Menu---
btnBuyCheat = KeyboardButton('️Купить читы')
btnNews = KeyboardButton('Hot Новости')
btnLifeHack = KeyboardButton('️Лайфхаки дня')
btnMyacc = KeyboardButton('Профиль')
btnAboutTheBot = KeyboardButton('О боте')
topUpMenu = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
mainMenu = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True).add(btnBuyCheat, btnNews, btnLifeHack, btnMyacc, btnAboutTheBot)

# ---Cheat For Game Menu---
btnCSGO = KeyboardButton('CS-GO')
btnDota2 = KeyboardButton('Dota2')
btnCODBO = KeyboardButton('Call Of Duty:Black Ops')
btnPUBG = KeyboardButton('PUBG')
btnST2 = KeyboardButton('Standoff2')
ChFoGaMeMenu = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True).add(btnCSGO, btnDota2, btnCODBO, btnPUBG, btnST2,  btnMain)

# ---Cheat For Game Menu---
btnToday = KeyboardButton('Today news')
btnYetday = KeyboardButton('Yesterday news')
newsMenu = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True).add(btnToday, btnYetday, btnMain)

# ---Lifehack for Game Menu---
btnShoot = KeyboardButton('Шутеры')
btnMMORPG = KeyboardButton('ММОРПГ')
btnStrateg = KeyboardButton('Стратегии')
btnMMOA = KeyboardButton('MMO Action[скоро!]')
LiHaMenu = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True).add(btnShoot, btnMMORPG, btnStrateg, btnMMOA, btnMain)

# ---About The Bot Menu---
btnWhoiam = KeyboardButton('Кто я?')
btnSogl = KeyboardButton('Соглашение')
aboutthebotMenu = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True).add(btnWhoiam, btnSogl, btnMain)

# ---Buy Cheat For CS-GO Menu---
btnCSBuy = KeyboardButton('Оплатить\n[CS-GO]')
buyCSMenu = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True).add(btnCSBuy, btnMain)

# ---Buy Cheat For Dota2  Menu---
btnDota2Buy = KeyboardButton('Оплатить\n[Dota2]')
buyDota2Menu = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True).add(btnDota2Buy, btnMain)

# ---Buy Cheat For Call Of Duty:Black Ops  Menu---
btnCallOfDutyBuy = KeyboardButton('Оплатить\n[Call Of Duty:Black Ops]')
buyCallOfDutyMenu = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True).add(btnCallOfDutyBuy, btnMain)

# ---Buy Cheat For PUBG  Menu---
btnPUBGBuy = KeyboardButton('Оплатить\n[PUBG]')
buyPUBGMenu = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True).add(btnPUBGBuy, btnMain)

# ---Buy Cheat For Standoff2  Menu---
btnStandoff2Buy = KeyboardButton('Оплатить\n[Standoff2]')
buyStandoff2Menu = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True).add(btnStandoff2Buy, btnMain)

# ---NewsToday Menu---
newsTMenu = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True).add(btnMain)

# ---NewsYesterday Menu---
newsYEMenu = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True).add(btnMain)

# ---Шутеры Menu---
newsShootMenu = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True).add(btnMain)

# ---ММОРПГ Menu---
newsMMORPGMenu = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True).add(btnMain)

# ---Стратегии---
newsStrategyMenu = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True).add(btnMain)

# ---MMO Action[скоро!] Menu---
newsMMOActionMenu = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True).add(btnMain)

# ---About Bot Menu---
newsWhoiambMenu = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True).add(btnMain)

# ---Bot Agreement Menu---
newsSoglbMenu = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True).add(btnMain)

# ---Profell Menu---
btnGlavn = KeyboardButton('Главное')
btnChek = KeyboardButton('Мои покупки')
myaccMenu = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True).add(btnGlavn, btnChek, btnMain)

# ---topUp Menu---
btnTopUp = InlineKeyboardButton(text="Оплатить!", callback_data="top_up")
topUpMenu.insert(btnTopUp)

def buy_menu(isUrl=True, url="", bill=""):
    qiwiMenu = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
    if isUrl:
        btnUrlQIWI = InlineKeyboardButton(text="Ссылка на оплату", url=url)
        qiwiMenu.insert(btnUrlQIWI)

    btnCheckQIWI = InlineKeyboardButton(text="Проверить оплату!", callback_data="check_"+bill)
    qiwiMenu.insert(btnCheckQIWI)
    return qiwiMenu

#__LifhackUrl__
ShootMenu = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
btnShoot2 = InlineKeyboardButton(text="Тут!", url="https://teletype.in/@uncle_cheat/Today_news_u_bot")
ShootMenu.insert(btnShoot2)

MMORPGMenu = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
btnMMORPG2 = InlineKeyboardButton(text="Тут!", url="https://teletype.in/@uncle_cheat/Today_news_u_bot")
MMORPGMenu.insert(btnMMORPG2)

Strateg2Menu = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
btnStrateg2 = InlineKeyboardButton(text="Тут!", url="https://teletype.in/@uncle_cheat/Today_news_u_bot")
Strateg2Menu.insert(btnStrateg2)

MMOA2Menu = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
btnMMOA2 = InlineKeyboardButton(text="Тут!", url="https://teletype.in/@uncle_cheat/Today_news_u_bot")
MMOA2Menu.insert(btnMMOA2)


#__News Today__
ntodayMenu = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
btnNewsToday = InlineKeyboardButton(text="Тут!", url="https://teletype.in/@uncle_cheat/Today_news_u_bot")
ntodayMenu.insert(btnNewsToday)

#__News YesToday__
nYetodayMenu = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
btnNewsYeToday = InlineKeyboardButton(text="Тут!", url="https://teletype.in/@uncle_cheat/Yest_News_Uncle_bot")
nYetodayMenu.insert(btnNewsYeToday)

#__AboutBot Today__
Whoiam2Menu = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
btnWhoiam2 = InlineKeyboardButton(text="Тут!", url="https://teletype.in/@uncle_cheat/Today_news_u_bot")
Whoiam2Menu.insert(btnWhoiam2)

#__SoglBot YesToday__
Sogl2Menu = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
btnSogl2 = InlineKeyboardButton(text="Тут!", url="https://teletype.in/@uncle_cheat/Yest_News_Uncle_bot")
Sogl2Menu.insert(btnSogl2 )
```

**config.py**

```
TOKEN = ""
QIWI_TOKEN = ""
```

**db.py**

```
import _sqlite3

class Database:
    def __init__(self, db_file):
        self.connection = _sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()

    def user_exists(self, user_id):
        with self.connection:
            result = self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE 'user_id' = ?", (user_id,)).fetchall()
            return bool(len(result))

    def add_user(self, user_id):
        with self.connection:
           return self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO users ('user_id') VALUES (?)", (user_id,))

    def user_money(self, user_id):
        with self.connection:
            result = self.cursor.execute("SELECT money FROM users WHERE user_id = ?", (user_id,)).fetchmany(1)
            return int(result[0][0])

    def set_money(self, user_id, user_money):
        with self.connection:
            return self.cursor.execute("UPDATE 'users' SET money = ? WHERE 'user_id' = ?", (user_money, user_id))

    def add_check(self, user_id, money, bill_id):
        with self.connection:
            return self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO 'check' ('user_id', 'money', 'bill_id') VALUES (?,?,?)", (user_id, money, bill_id,))

    def get_check(self, bill_id):
        with self.connection:
            result = self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM 'check' WHERE bill_id = ?", (bill_id,)).fetchmany(1)
            if not bool(len(result)):
                return False
            return result[0]

    def delete_check(self, bill_id):
        with self.connection:
            return self.cursor.execute("DELETE FROM `check` WHERE `bill_id` = ?", (bill_id,))
```

Я не могу представить как решить эту проблему, возможно вы поможете мне...Пожалуйста!

Comment: Бот выдаёт ошибку? Кнопка точно с нужным callback?

Comment: @dp.callback_query_handler(text_contains="check_") Исправил. После в markups изменил инлайн маркап на реплай маркап, бот обработал и ответил что счет не оплачен, но после этого кнопки переместились за место клавиатуры и перестали работать.

Comment: Все, решил проблему, переписал код и ошибка пропала, спасибо за то, что обратили внимание в callback, видимо в нем и была проблема.